# Tangent Plane for a Level Set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am currently looking at the following theorem which I know how to prove from one side but not from the another side:

**Theorem**: If $a$ is a regular value of a smooth function $F:U\subset\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $p \in F^{-1}(a)=S$, then the tangent plane $T_pS=(\nabla F(p))^{\perp}$.

The definition of surfaces and tangent planes follow the textbook "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" by M. do Carmo.

Now, I know how to prove $T_pS\subset(\nabla F(p))^{\perp}$ simply by chain rule. But I have no idea how to prove the another side of the subset relation, because what I need to do is that given $u \in (\nabla F(p))^{\perp}$, I need a curve $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow S$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=u$, but I have no idea how to find such a curve.

Comment: Once you know the inclusion that you wrote you can conclude by noticing that both spaces are two dimensional, so they have to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

For $u\in ( \nabla F(p))^\perp$, $$ \frac{d}{dt} \ F(p+tu) =0$$

Here $c(t)=p+tu$ so that $$ F\circ c(t)= a + \frac{1}{2}t^2
D^2F(u,u)  +  O(t^3)
$$

If $c_2(t)=p+tu+ \frac{1}{2}t^2 A \nabla F$, then $$ F\circ c_2(t)=
a+ \frac{1}{2}t^2  \underbrace{\{ D^2F(u,u)  + A \nabla F\cdot
\nabla F \}}_{=K}  + O(t^3)
$$

For some $A$, we have $K=0$ so that we can approximate curve
$\alpha$ with $F|\alpha =a$.

Comment: Sorry I can't see how does the first equality hold.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} F=\nabla F\cdot u =0$ by choosing $u$

Comment: But we only got $\nabla F(p) \bullet u=0$ by definition, but what you stated is $\nabla F(p+tu) \bullet u=0$?

Comment: I mean at $t=0$.

Comment: Sorry I also can't understand your notation: what does it mean by $D^2F(u,u)$? Moreover, how does the third equality hold? I can't see why you can simply replace $c_1$ by $c_2$.

Comment: We want to find a curve $\alpha$ with $F\circ \alpha =a$ In second equality we have hessian of $F$, i.e. $D^2F$ That is, to rule out this term, we consider $c_2$. In such a way we approximate $\alpha$ with curves $c,\ c_2$ and so on.